Upper and lower case sensitivity when entering entities, but inconsistent
When you type Entity["Chemical", "Hydrogen"] or Entity["Chemical", "hydrogen"] it will be recognized as an chemical entity as intended, regardless the upper/lower case. However, this does not work with Entity["Chemical", "chlorine"]. I think that is clearly a bug.

So ... where is the question? :) If you believe this is a bug, you should report it to Wolfram Technical Support.

Sure, I can report that. I was wondering if this is a common design flaw or if I missed something. Btw, here are the other unrecognized elements as chemicals: "carbon", "nitrogen", "oxygen", "fluorine", "magnesium", "phosphorus", "sulfur", "arsenic", "selenium", "bromine", "tin", "iodine", "berkelium". That was certainly not the intention.

If you also look at other entities, they almost always have capitalized names in the input form. So I would say the fact that "hydrogen" works is an exception here.

I am trying to figure out how "hydrogen" works, because as far as I can tell "hydrogen" is not listed in the "PrivateStandardNames" in the internal ElementData database. Will post an answer when I've figured it out.  Interpreter["Element"]["hydrogen"] is the documented method for doing this.
